# Does log4j2 async logger actually insert data into MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, log4j2

I know that log4j2 is for logging information. I'm really confused about the log4jdbc appender. What does it actually do? I read the tutorials but I really don't understand it. Does it log the informations as you insert data into database via jdbc?? or does log4j2 logger actually ABLE to log into database?

Regular jdbc can do things like:

```
String query ="INSERT INTO 'table' ('blah' ...";
Statement st;
st.executeUpdate(query);
```

does log4j async logger actually have something equivalent to --> [st.executeUpdate(query);] which insert data a lot faster??

Thank you for your effort!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log4j2 JDBC appender will use JDBC and insert rows per each log event.

> The JDBCAppender writes log events to a relational database table
>   using standard JDBC.
>   *http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#JDBCAppender*

As for

> does log4j async logger actually have something equivalent to -->
>   [st.executeUpdate(query);] which insert data a lot faster??

The async appenders do not do batch inserting (batch execution `executeBatch`) which is what I assuming your referring to. The batch inserting is controlled I assume by `bufferSize` in the JDBC appender (see previous link).

The async appenders are decorators (they wrap appenders like the JDBC one) that just make it so your code does not block when a appender blocks (ie when `executeBatch` is done in this case).

There is also another project which I think your confused with [log4jdbc-log4j2](http://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc-log4j2/). That project will log your SQL statements using log4j2.